# RTK Query cache keys for nested resource url

Tags: rtk-query

Maybe this is based on me mis-using RTK Query,
however I have the following issue:

given an url like this `/api/newspaper/posts/12345/comments`

i fetch the comments like so

```
getPostComments: build.query<Comments[], void>({
  query: () => constructQueryUrl('/comments'),
  // more omitted code
```

`constructQueryUrl` extracts the post id from the urlParams in a shared helper file,
this way i do not have to extract and pass them in every component where i use `getPostComments`

this is nice to use and works great... till i decide to switch posts,
and try to query that posts comments

due to how RTKQ is handling caching the key for storing this request and its data will be:
`getPostComments(undefined)`

Q:

- am i using RTKQ wrong?
- is there a way to make the `query` function consider the actual url as well when caching
- is `serializeQueryArgs` the way to go on issues like this?

Thanks in advance for any helpful comments/ answers

Answer (score 0):

That cache key is an implementation detail and you should never try to access the cache entry that way. It could be `"asdik;jai;osd"` and that would be perfectly fine.

Generally, you are using RTKQ a bit wrong here - your `query` function should be pure - it will only run again if your query hook is called with different arguments. So your `id` needs to be an argument to `useGetPostComments` for this to work.

Comment: hi @phry, thanks for your quick reply, i know you must be very busy ‍♀️    

i think i didn't make it very clear, the issue is not that the key is generated, i'm also not accessing it by hand in any way.    

what i mean, is the fact, that the same key is used from two separate `posts` thus comments for the other one are not being pulled, because under the hood RTKQ seems to assume "`getPostComments(undefined)` is the same for both ‍♀️, no need to re-fetch, i already got the response for that key"    
   
  
   
did that explanation make more sense?   
thanks in advance

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that. Yes, you are using RTK Query kind of wrong here. Calling your `useGetPostComments()` hook with the same arguments should also result in the same data being fetched. So in your case, you should not extract that from an external source inside of your `query` function, but you should be calling `useGetPostComments(id)` from the outside.

Comment: thanks,  

"Calling your `useGetPostComments()` hook with the same arguments should also result in the same data being fetched."

ah, that's too bad - i would've thought that the query itself is also "url aware" 
i guess that would make the query cache keying that much more complex though 

thank you for your work and swift reply here ‍♂️

If you adjust your answer to the comment i can also mark it as the appropriate/ correct 